# when muxing h264 to mp4 (isobmff format), Endian processing method

Tags: c, video, mp4, h.264, endianness

If video data muxing to mp4 file, video raw data -> mdat

A typical MP4 layout:

```
[MDAT size in 4 bytes] --> [MDAT header in 4 bytes "m","d","a","t"] then follows NALUs.
[NAL #1 size (4 bytes)] --> [NAL #1 data] --> [NAL #2 size (4 bytes)] --> [NAL #2 data].
```

But when i try this using isobmff library, It needs to Endian processing method.
My CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6238R CPU @ 2.20GHz.
Not only ASCII Code `'m' 'd' 'a' 't'`  change to `'t' 'a' 'd' 'm'` but also size bytes change to BigEndian.
After Endian Proccessing Little->Big, It makes work.
But, without Endian processing, I can not make mp4 mdat box.
Is it right to do it this way?

Are the ASCII code and size of the mp4 box in big-endian format?

Answer (score 1):

MP4 file specification came out of MOV (Apple's format).

Apple's early hardware was big endian but your Intel Xeon is little endian.

So the size field in MP4 is big endian so you have to convert from little endian to big endian before you write to the file.

The fourCC 'mdat' (4 bytes "m","d","a","t") needs to be written in the order as spelled.

Sometimes libraries store fourCC s like 'mdat' in uint32_t and then the fourCC  may get reversed.